# get ETH on mumbai network on my metamask wallet

Tags: faucets

I need some ETH on mumbai network on my metamask wallet to buy an item on opensea mumbai testnet.
I already searched on the web without success.
how to get them?

Thanks

Comment: If it's gas tokens your looking for, Mumbai and Polygon use matic instead of eth.

Comment: @SlothMan no, I need ETH.

Comment: Did you try their faucet https://faucet.polygon.technology/?

Comment: @Ismael yes, but in that url I cannot choose ETH for mumbai, because the only token available for mumbai is MATIC.

Comment: I'm also interested in this! For testing purposes, I'm trying to buy an NFT on testnets.opensea.io on the Mumbai testnet. But that requires ETH, which I haven't figured out how to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://staging.aave.com/#/faucet

Select polygon mumbai on the upper right corner

Comment: Is that for put WETH on the faucet or to get WETH on my wallet? It prompt a transaction with a fee!

Comment: it puts the token you select onto your wallet, make sure you add the token to your metamask (or wallet of choice) to be able to see your balance

Comment: But why does it ask for a transaction with fee?? It should be free for me because the tx is made by the website

Comment: the one who initiates the transaction pays the fees, in that case you. But it does not matter as it is the testnet anyways

Comment: It works, thanks! 10 WETH for each transaction!

Comment: I don't see eth on the given page

Comment: Is not for get eth, its for stake your eth,,,

Comment: looks like they removed the faucet

Comment: THe site  not work

Answer (score 4):

I was stumped by this too, but then found that you can bridge on OpenSea from the Goerli ETH to Poly ETH.
You can get Goerli ETH on several test faucets (like on Chainlink).
In OpenSea testnets, you can then click on the wallet icon, click on the dots to get the option to 'Bridge to Mumbai'.

[image]

Comment: I bridged as you said but it is gone now and I don't know where my Goerli ether went. Should I import the token to Polygon Testnet account somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I can use Mumbai Matic only to deploy the contract and to mint NFTs. But I cannot use Mumbai Matic for trades on the OpenSea test network. I could offer an NFT without problems (offering an NFT does not cost anything). But I could not buy this NFT using a second account. Neither with Rinkeby Ether nor with Mumbai Matic. Mumbai Matics contained in Metamask will not be listed in Opensea as currency usable for trades.

Then I got Göerli Ether from a faucet like described by Sylvia. In Opensea this Göerli Ether I could bridge to Mumbai Ether (obviously it does not work with Rinkeby Ether). This Mumbai Ether now was available in Opensea to buy a NFT from a contract deployed to the Mumbai testnet. Thank you Silyia ;-)

At the moment it is very difficulty to geht Göerli Ether. The only way I could find out is the Alchemy Göerli faucet (https://goerlifaucet.com/) where you can get 0.1 Göerli each day.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Sylvia I transfered some ETH into the Goerli testned the Alchemy faucet (https://goerlifaucet.com/) and then Bridged to the Mumbai network, however, event if I waited severals hours, I wasn't able to find those ETH in my wallet in the Mumbai network.

**Edit:** after few hours I was able to see the ETH on the Mumbai Network on OpenSea.

[image]